# Why BigInt(2 ** 100) does return a correct result in Chrome, Firefox, Safari

Tags: javascript, bigint

I would expect the number that I pass to BigInt has already overflowed before the BigInt creation, yet the result is correct. What is the reason, and can I rely on this for other powers of 2 (my use case)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: TL;DR - powers of 2 up to 1023

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering!
@VLAZ if you don't understand what is the question is about do not edit it!

Comment: @Patman your question is whether or not you can use BigInt with powers of 2. It doesn't appear to be relevant why it works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. As in an answer addressing that wouldn't satisfy you, an answer talking about number representation and BigInt would. Is that incorrect? Do you actually want to know about these three browsers specifically?

Comment: Also, there is no need to repeatedly post the same comment to me.

Comment: No, my question was why i'm able to provide a number that exceeds max safe int to BigInt constructor and still get the correct BigInt. (the number I'm taliking about is the result of calculation 2*100. You can think about it as:
const temporaryVariableThatShouldOverflow = 2**100
const properBigInt = BigInt(temporaryVariableThatShouldOverflow);
I was mentioning v8 and non v8 browsers, as I didn't know the reason for this behaviour. And @VLAZ seriously, please stop editing my posts again and again.

Comment: @Patman Feel free to flag for moderator attention if you have a strong case why your post should stay grammatically incorrect. I'll just use the platform as it's designed to be used with collaborative editing.

Comment: I probably prefer to have a grammatical mistake, but not change the original question to complete nonsense.

Comment: @Patman your question bodu literally already asks whether you can use large powers of two. Putting it in the title makes the question explicitly about that. What seems more like nonsense is "Why does this code work in three random browsers" which doesn't describe what you're actually after. I am starting to question whether it was me who misread the question or you misread the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the JavaScript `number` type follows the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard for floating point numbers. These numbers are stored like this:

- Sign bit (in your example `+1`)
- Exponent (in your example `100`)
- Fractional part (in your example `.0`)

... to represent a number like `sign * (1 + fractional part) * 2 ** exponent`. In your case, that number is `+1 * (1 + .0) * 2 ** 100`.

You can see that it can store powers of two exactly.

You can't *completely* depend on it, though. This format is fixed size and so can only represent a finite number of numbers. The largest power of two that can be represented is `2 ** 1023`. Trying to do `BigInt(2 ** 1024)` will throw a `RangeError`, because floating point numbers that are too large to be represented in 64 bits are represented with a special `Infinity` value.

You are not going to get an inexact value, though, if that's the most important aspect for you.

Should you need to deal with larger values, I suggest storing the exponent as a number and then doing `2n ** BigInt(my_exponent)` when you need the BigInt. (Or BigInt(2) ** BigInt(my_exponent)`).

Comment: Considering [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) is recommended to be used only when the number is greater than 2^53, `2n ** BigInt(my_exponent)` becomes quite big.

Comment: It can become quite large, yes, but considering OP hasn't yet run into a `RangeError` I don't think their use case involves numbers _that_ large.

Comment: Just want to mention a possible alternative `BigInt("0b1" + "0".repeat(power))` - would also work to construct a big int with the appropriate value. I'd prefer a `BigInt(2) ** BigInt(power)` in almost all circumstances but the string might have some niche application where it's better. I can't really think of any, though.

Comment: @VLAZ: while that string alternative works, it's much less efficient. Nothing wrong with `2n ** BigInt(power)`, or straight-up `2n ** 100n` if the power is a constant. `1n << BigInt(power)` also works.